# ROS on raspberry pi Zero

Tags: raspberrypi

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I have an Ubuntu 14.04 laptop which I use at work with ROS Jade installed in it, so I'm not allowed to do any changes to it. I recently bought a Raspberry Pi Zero (with Raspbian Lite) and wanted to install ROS in it, but I don't know if I will be able to use the same packages I use in my laptop inside the raspberry.

The idea is to have a package in my laptop to do stuff, another one in the RPI and another one, which will be shared between both computers, that will handle all the WiFi communications between them.

I couldn't find any info saying if it's ok to install Jade in the PiZero, so I wanted to make sure before starting doing it.
Maybe I should also note that my idea is to add an Arduino into the setup.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/241214/ros-on-raspberry-pi-zero/) by [lluk12](https://answers.ros.org/users/27693/lluk12/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2016-08-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It should be possible, only concern is if zero will be powerfull enough for what you want to do and packages...

if you can find repository with packages, you should have no problems.
If you can't find, it will be tricky, because you need to compile ros from source and some packages take over 1GB RAM easily, which means you have to use swap on zero.... and that will make it slow as hell (not to mention that CPU itself will compile everything for a long time)... also, you propably want to put swap file on flashdrive over usb, rather than killing microsd ...

---

Originally posted by [veverak](https://answers.ros.org/users/25419/veverak/) with karma: 51 on 2016-08-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [lluk12](https://answers.ros.org/users/27693/lluk12/) on 2016-08-07**:
What if I install Kinetic instead of Jade? Will have much problems to make it work?

**Comment by [veverak](https://answers.ros.org/users/25419/veverak/) on 2016-08-07**:
it should be easier, kinetic is at least targeted for debian jessie, just different architecture (it means you won't have to figure out all dependencies for ros to solve), on the other hand there is still compilation time...

And I am actually blocked in making reliable raspbian repository ...